# Complexity of the NetworkX function 'is_chordal'

Tags: python, complexity-theory

I am searching for the complexity of the [method `is_chordal` of the NetworkX library](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/_modules/networkx/algorithms/chordal/chordal_alg.html#is_chordal)

```
def is_chordal(G):
    if G.is_directed():
        raise nx.NetworkXError('Directed graphs not supported')
    if G.is_multigraph():
        raise nx.NetworkXError('Multiply connected graphs not supported.')
    if len(_find_chordality_breaker(G))==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Everything in that code is O(1) (the `is_...` methods just return `True` or `False`). The complexity thus hinges on [`_find_chordiality_breaker`](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/algorithms/chordal.py#L284)

Comment: and in your opinion what is the complexity of _find_chordality_breaker (G)? @timgeb

Comment: If they did not break it, it should be as documented: `Based on the algorithms in [1]_. -> [1] R. E. Tarjan and M. Yannakakis, Simple linear-time algorithms 
       to test chordality of graphs, test acyclicity of hypergraphs, and 
       selectively reduce acyclic hypergraphs, SIAM J. Comput., 13 (1984), 
       pp. 566–579.`